# What is the meaning of the `[_]` pattern in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

When creating pattern matches in Haskell, does the following pattern match:

```
function [_] = []
```

mean the same as:

```
function (x:xs) = []
```

If not, what does the `[_]` pattern mean?

Comment: The list syntax is confusing because *a*) syntacic sugar, which you are running into *b*) same syntax for the list (type) constructor and the empty list (value-level): `[]` *c*) same syntax for list (type) and singleton list (value): `[a]`. Think in terms of `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` instead of `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`, then your example of `[_]` becomes `Cons _ Nil` and is clearly different from `Cons x xs`.

Comment: `[x1,x2,...,xn]` is equivalent to `(x1:x2:...:xn:[])`, both in patterns and expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[_]` matches a list with *one* element; `x:xs` matches any non-empty list, with the side effect of binding the head to `x` and the tail to `xs`.

`[_]` is equivalent to `(_:[])`.

Given

```
f x = case x of 
        [_] -> "singleton"
        [] -> "empty"
        otherwise -> "nonempty"
```

then

```
> print $ map f [[], [1], [1,2]]
["empty","singleton","nonempty"]
```